# download file without extension / download and wait until finished

Tags: javascript, file, download

Two JS questions I googled a lot and couldn't find an answer:
a) I try to load a file without extension but get an error.
b) I can't find a solution to load a file and wait until it has finished.
The URLs below are real files so you can try it yourself.

```
// ad a)
var wl_version = "";
var wl_wkt     = "";

function download(nr, url) {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open("GET", url);
  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (nr == 1) {wl_version = client.responseText;}
    if (nr == 6) {wl_wkt     = client.responseText;}
  }
  client.send();
}

function getdata() {
  download(1, "https://data.wien.gv.at/csv/wienerlinien-ogd-version.csv");  // THAT WORKS !!!
  download(6, "https://go.gv.at/l9ogdwienerlinienteilstreckenwkt");  // THAT DOESN'T WORK !!!
}

// ----------------------------------------------

// ad b)
function httpRequestAsync(url, callback) {
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => { 
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {  // THAT DOESN'T WORK, FUNCTION DOESN'T WAIT UNTIL DOWNLOAD HAS FINISHED
      callback(httpRequest.responseText);
    }
  }
  httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
  httpRequest.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, it's impossible to attach an event before and after a download through javascript. Browser doesn't allow this type of events for security reasons.

but for download a file you also can open your file url in new tab with javascript.

```
window.open('https://data.wien.gv.at/csv/wienerlinien-ogd-version.csv', '_blank')
```

Comment: No, sorry, thats not what I want because I want to process the downloaded data, but I don't know when I can start processing.